# How to merge Series to DataFrame where Series index match some column value?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame `df`:

```
           date  cases  country
0    2020-12-14     63       AF
1    2020-12-13     71       AF
2    2020-12-12    110       AF
3    2020-12-11     91       AF
...
501  2020-12-14     14       BE
502  2020-12-13     22       BE
503  2020-12-12     19       BE
504  2020-12-11     35       BE
...
```

I also have a Series `casesPerDay`:

```
date
2019-12-31    0
2020-01-01    0
2020-01-02   46
2020-02-03   58
...
```

I want to add `casesPerDay` to `df` so that the `date` column in `df` matches the `date` index in `casesPerDay`.

For example if there were only the 2 countries above it would look like this:

```
           date  cases  country  casePerDay  # just the sum of cases
0    2020-12-14     63       AF          77  # 63 + 14
1    2020-12-13     71       AF          93  # 71 + 22
2    2020-12-12    110       AF         129  # 110 + 19
3    2020-12-11     91       AF         126  # 91 + 35
...
501  2020-12-14     14       BE          77  # 63 + 14
502  2020-12-13     22       BE          93  # 71 + 22
503  2020-12-12     19       BE         129  # 110 + 19
504  2020-12-11     35       BE         126  # 91 + 35
...
```

Comment: How does `casesPerDay` dataframe play a part in your shown output? I dont see any matches... on *date column in df matches the date index in casesPerDay*

Comment: The date in `casesPerDay` should match the date in `df`. For the example, I added the `cases` for the two countries just for examples sake. In the real thing I am looking to just append the values from `casesPerDay` based on the date attribute.

Comment: *I added the cases for the two countries just for examples sake* :- > not quite clear since none match and we can't reproduce to get the output you show... : try `df.merge(casesPerDay,left_on='date',right_index=True)`, please also read [how to create a readable and reproducible pandas example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Answer (score 2):

What we can do is

```
out = df.merge(casesPerDay.to_frame('casePerDay').reset_index())
```